# Disable automatic retry for Azure Durable Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I would like to disable automatic retry in the Azure Durable Function.
So whenever there is an error just stop executing and do not retry it again.

I updated host.json with the following settings but it seems not working.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "retry": {
    "strategy": "fixedDelay",
    "maxRetryCount": 0,
    "delayInterval": "00:00:00"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 0
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I still can see queue messages in mystorageaccountname-workitems queue.

Answer (score 1):

Disable automatic retry for Azure Durable Function

To disable retry option in your durable function, add a function

```
[FunctionName("TimerOrchestratorWithRetry")]
public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var retryOptions = new RetryOptions(
        firstRetryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        maxNumberOfAttempts: 3);

    await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("FlakyFunction", retryOptions, null);

    // ...
}
```

Options to customize Automatic retry policy:

- **Max number of attempts**: The maximum number of attempts. If set to 1, there will be no retry.
- **First retry interval**: The amount of time to wait before the first retry attempt.
  for further reference check [Automatic Retry Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp#automatic-retry-on-failure) docs for durable functions.